# Prove that trigonometric equation isn't changed by value of x

Tags: trigonometry

$\sqrt{\sin^4x+\cos2x} + \sqrt{\cos^4x-\cos2x}$ I have to prove that $x$ doesn't matter. However I can't get things to simplify.

Comment: Note: to establish your target result, set $x=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. One has
$$
\sin^4x+\cos2x=\sin^4x+2 \cos^2x-1=\sin^4x-2 \sin^2x+1
$$ and
$$
\cos^4x-\cos2x=\cos^4x-2 \cos^2x+1
$$ Can you finish it?

Comment: The second equation is $\cos^4x-\cos 2x$ but the idea is the same. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

HINT: show that $$\sin(x)^4+\cos(2x)=\cos(x)^4$$ and $$\cos(x)^4-\cos(2x)=\sin(x)^4$$

Comment: It's not hard to be right when you rely on Mathematica@.